# constructing complex sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to select and update a table looking up values from other tables. The idea is to select some details from order, but get the names of the foreign key values using the id

For the select I tried:

```
SELECT [Order].order_date, 
       [Order].total_price, 
       [Order].order_details,
       vehicle.reg_no,
       Staff.name,
       stock.name 
FROM 
       Order,
       vehicle,
       staff,
       stock
WHERE
      order.id = @order_id 
  AND vehicle.id = Order.vehicle_id 
  AND staff.id = Order.staff_id 
  AND stock.id = Order.product_id
```

for the update  that i tried

```
UPDATE order 
SET 
    total_price = @total_price, 
    order_detail = @order_detail,
    product_id = (select is from stock where name = @product_name), 
    customer_id = (select id  from customer where name = @customer_name), 
    vehicle_regno = (select reg_no  from vehicle where name = @name)
WHERE (id = @id)
```

both does not return anything. i hope am clear enough to get some help, but if not pls i will provide more info.

thanks for helping

Comment: Do you mean that nothing is updated or that you get no results - since update statements do not give multiple results like select statements do (only number of rows updated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try converting you INNER JOINs to a LEFT JOIN for the SELECT statement.

```
SELECT [Order].order_date, 
       [Order].total_price, 
       [Order].order_details,
       vehicle.reg_no,
       Staff.name,
       stock.name 
FROM 
       [Order] 
       LEFT JOIN vehicle
       ON vehicle.id = [Order].vehicle_id 
       LEFT JOIN staff
       ON staff.id = [Order].staff_id
       LEFT JOIN stock
       ON stock.id = [Order].product_id
WHERE
      [order].id = @order_id
```

The reasons why this would make a difference is if either a) you allow nulls in the fk fields or b) you don't have fk contraints which may point to a problem with your design.

Your update statement should update some rows provided that the value of @id exists in the ORDER table but as  [@Danny Varod already commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194831/constructing-complex-sql-statement/10195075#comment13088334_10194831) you won't get rows back only the number of rows affected

Comment: thanks, this worked. can you help on the update satement, i guess am getting it wrong

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by wrong. e.g. you get `0 record(s) updated` or null values for vehicle.id

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing `stock.id` with `Order.product_id`, could that be the problem?
Otherwise why it is not returning any rows we would need to know the content of the tables, perhaps you need a `left join` instead of `inner join` to some of them?

Comment: no its not the problem the product_id is the id in the stock table